# How to remove firebase "onChildAdded" listener in dart

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database, listener

I'm currently using Dart and Firebase and seem to be unable to remove an onChildAdded listener.
To add a listener I do the following:

`_messagesRef.child(userID).onChildAdded.listen(_onUserMessageAdded);`

To remove a listener, the firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/lists-of-data#detach_listeners) states

> Callbacks are removed by calling the off() method on your Firebase database reference.
> You can remove a single listener by passing it as a parameter to off(). Calling off() on the >location with no arguments removes all listeners at that location.
> Calling off() on a parent listener does not automatically remove listeners registered on its child >nodes; off() must also be called on any child listeners to remove the callback.

The documentation states that you can call off on a location to remove all listeners. When I try to call off() however, it does not seem to be a method of the DatabaseReference class. 
`_messagesRef.child(userID).off();`
The above code will not compile and gives the error
`Error: The method 'off' isn't defined for the class 'DatabaseReference'.`

Any help with understanding how to remove a listener would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The documentation is incorrect and likely for JavaScript instead of dart. Use the `cancel` method on the [StreamSubscription](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/StreamSubscription-class.html) object returned by [listen](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/listen.html).